# Issue on web-scraping with GET Requests and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an URL using `BeautifulSoup`.

Below is my code:

```
url= 'https://www.clinicspots.com/what-is-the-knee-replacement-surgery-cost-in-india'
response = requests.get(url)

s4 = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
s4
```

Furthermore, I need to do perform `s4.title.text`.

***This is giving me some weird output (seem to be written in Chinese)***

I tried to open the URL manually, and this seems to be working fine.

I am not sure how to fix this. Please suggest.

EDIT #1: Below is the screen capture of the output:

[image]

Comment: what it's giving you ? you've to show us! otherwise we aren't a translation service here. is your question related to programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `s4 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')` instead of `s4 = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}  

url= 'https://www.clinicspots.com/what-is-the-knee-replacement-surgery-cost-in-india'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
s4 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(s4)
```